# IBDesignable not working UIButton alignments?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am subclassing UIButton, trying to align them through programmatically but it does not working.
The same thing i can align them in **stoaryboard**. Why its not working?

See my code below:

```
  @IBDesignable
class AddProfilePictureView: UIButton {
    
    open var bottomLineLayer : CALayer?
    
    @IBInspectable var textColor:UIColor = .gray{
        didSet{ self.titleLabel?.textColor = textColor }
    }

    @IBInspectable var leftHandImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            leftHandImage = leftHandImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            setupImages()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var rightHandImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            rightHandImage = rightHandImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            setupImages()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var bottomLineColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray {
        didSet {
            addBottomLine()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var imageSize: CGFloat = 20{
        didSet {
            setupImages()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var titlePadding: CGFloat = 25{
        didSet {
            alignment()
        }
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
         super.init(frame: frame)
        alignment()
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        alignment()
     }

     override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
         super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        alignment()
     }
    
    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var tempRect = contentRect
        tempRect.origin.x = titlePadding
        return tempRect
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        addBottomLine()
    }
    func alignment(){
        contentVerticalAlignment = .bottom
    }
    func  addBottomLine(){
//        if bottomLineLayer == nil{
        for layer in self.layer.sublayers  ?? [] {
             if layer.name == "bottom" {
                  layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
             }
         }
            bottomLineLayer = CALayer()
            bottomLineLayer?.name = "bottom"
            bottomLineLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.height + 5, width: self.frame.width, height: 1.0)
            bottomLineLayer?.backgroundColor = bottomLineColor.cgColor
            self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLineLayer ?? CALayer())
//        }
    }
    func setupImages() {
        
        if let rightImage = rightHandImage {
            for views in self.subviews{
                if views.tag == 100{
                    views.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
            let rightImageView = UIImageView(image: rightImage)
            rightImageView.tag = 100
            rightImageView.tintColor = .black
            self.addSubview(rightImageView)
            rightImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                rightImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor,constant: 0),
//                rightImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
                rightImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor,constant: 0),
                rightImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageSize),
                rightImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageSize)
            ])
        }
        
        if let rightImage = leftHandImage {
            for views in self.subviews{
                if views.tag == 101{
                    views.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
            let rightImageView = UIImageView(image: rightImage)
            rightImageView.tintColor = .black
            rightImageView.tag = 101
            self.addSubview(rightImageView)
            rightImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                rightImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor,constant: 0),
//                rightImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
                rightImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor,constant: 0),
                rightImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageSize),
                rightImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageSize)
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

This line does nothing

```
contentVerticalAlignment = .bottom
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not calling super method of layoutSubviews.
Try this

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    addBottomLine()
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but still not working

Comment: I tried your class and It's working fine when I run my app.

Comment: How strange? Check my updated question and try modified code

Comment: Using this code, you solved your last problem(It's your original question). Right?

Comment: I solved left alignment, but text has to come bottom as well that is not working

Comment: Yes, It's not working through code. You can override rect properties of UIButton or set edge insets.

Comment: Setting set edge insets not adopt to if text is multiline..

Comment: Then I suggest you set ContentVerticalAlignment by storyboard

Comment: thats fine, need to understand the root cause